# How to copy files/directories from a Linux/Ubuntu machine to Ubuntu subsystem in Windows while preserving permissions

Tags: dual-boot, rsync

I'm trying to send files from my full Ubuntu version in dual-boot to my other Ubuntu subsystem version within Windows 10. What I usually do is that I mount my windows partition that has the Ubuntu subsystem files into my full Ubuntu version, then I do a `cp -r source destination`. I tried the other alternative which is to use rsync. However, the problem with both methods is that when I switch to my Linux subsystem within W10, I get "permission denied" whenever I try to get into the directories that I copied OR edit files. The workaround of this issue is to manually give 755 and 644 permissions after switching to the Linux subsystem when the copying process is done, but I don't think that this is the right way to do this whole process.

My current method is to tar the files up in my full Ubuntu version, then copy the tar to the Linux subsystem, this method still requires me to give a 755 permission (or untar with sudo), and after the file extraction, all the files have the sufficient permissions. But then again, I still need to use either sudo or give some sort of permission after switching to the Linux subsystem to untar the files. Any ideas on what is the optimal way to send files from a dual boot Ubuntu to the Linux subsystem in my Windows partition?

Comment: are you sure the issue isn't ownership rather than permissions? I doubt the username generated by windows is exactly the same as the one you chose when installing you ubuntu. if you want to change a files's ower here's how you do it : `sudo chmod -R riyadh the_folder/` or `sudo chmod riyadh the_file/` you cannot change owners and cp in the same command, you'll have to do one and then the other. `cp -rp` preserves rights : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43605/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-keeping-owners-and-permissions-intact

Comment: But we can do `sudo chmod -R riyah /path/to/the_folder/ && sudo cp -rp /path/to/the_folder`, the second command will run if the first succeeds!

Comment: Thank you both for the replies! Unfourtantly, I tried to mess around with both preserving permissions and changing ownership, neither worked. I think instead of "chmod" it should've been "chown". Anyhow, the problem is that when copying with -rp, the files that are copied into the Linux subsystem still has "0" permissions. Furthermore, when I try to change the owner from my full Ubuntu version (dual-boot) the response is "invalid user" mainly because the Linux-subsystem user is not located within the same disk partition.

Comment: I need to note, however, the 0 permission issue only appears when I switch to the Linux subsystem. Logically, when I access the copied files from the full Ubuntu partition, I obviously have all the permissions retained. The issue is when i copy files from the dual-boot Linux to the Linux W10 subsystem and try to access them from the Linux subsystem